# Javascript: Function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've installed a google map element to my page and I want it to be able to change the location of the store on clicking a link

Here's the html

```
<div class="mapnav">
    <h5>Select a map:</h5>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="location" onclick="resetMap(21.535176, 39.177557)">Madinah Road Branch</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="location" onclick="resetMap(21.535176, 49.177557)">Prince Sultan St. Branch</a>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="location" onclick="resetMap(22.535176, 39.177557)">Sharqiya Branch</a>
</div>
```

and here's the javascript - I've defined a resetMap function inside the original google map function on an external script

```
function resetMap(newLatitude, newLongitude){
  //reset google map options
  var map_options = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(newLatitude, newLongitude),
    zoom: map_zoom,
    panControl: false,
    zoomControl: false,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false,
    styles: style,
  }
  //reinizialize the map

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('google-container'), map_options);

  //add a custom marker to the map              
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(newLatitude, newLongitude),
    map: map,
    visible: true,
    icon: marker_url,
  });
}
```

I keep getting a function not defined error in the console. I have been looking around many threads but most on the same topic are very specific to the individual problem.

Comment: Read what you wrote: "resetMap function inside the original google map function". Functions within functions cannot be seen outside the scope which they are defined.

Answer (score 0):

> ive defined a resetMap function inside the original google map function

Function declarations are scoped just like `var`. It isn't defined, because you are trying to access it in the global scope and it only exists inside the other function.

Move it so it is a global.

Answer (score 0):

> ive defined a resetMap function inside the original google map
>   function on an external script

If you have defined `function` (or anything) inside a `function` (Google Map function as you mentioned), it won't be in global scope anymore.

You can either

1. Define the function in global scope (not inside any function/method),

2) Or explicitly put the method in window's scope (global scope) by doing

```
window.resetMap = function (newLatitude, newLongitude){
```

Unless the function is not in global scope, you won't be able to invoke it via direct-event-handlers (like onclick attribute event handler)

Another approach could be to assign the events via `addEventListener` where the method is in scope.

For example

```
function resetMap(newLatitude, newLongitude)
{
 //code here
}
//Event assignment here
$(".mapnav a.location").bind("click", function(){  
  var lat = parseFloat($(this).attr("data-lat"));
  var long= parseFloat($(this).attr("data-long"));
  resetMap(lat, long )
})
```

while your markup will look like

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="location" data-lat="21.535176" data-long="39.177557">Madinah Road Branch</a>
```

Comment: brilliant, the second option of putting the method in the windows scope is exactly what i needed as i was using var's from the initial function thats why i needed it nested inside the google map function to avoid redefining many variables